# Eclipse scala-ide won't start after installing Mac OS X Sierra (Mac OS 10.12)

Tags: eclipse, scala, scala-ide

Eclipse quit Unexpectedly error is showing up.

> Process:               eclipse [1612] Path:
>   /Applications/Eclipse.app/Contents/MacOS/eclipse Identifier:
>   scalaide.product.id Version:               1.0.0 (1.0.0.201605041117)
>   Code Type:             X86-64 (Native) Parent Process:        ??? [1]
>   Responsible:           eclipse [1612] User ID:               501
>
> Date/Time:             2016-11-05 08:25:36.767 +0530 OS Version:
>   Mac OS X 10.12 (16A323) Report Version:        12 Anonymous UUID:
>   756B4B0B-5772-3B0B-F072-86AA384C8784
>
> Sleep/Wake UUID:       9458E0FB-8ADB-4FF1-AF46-A0CE9A6FC72D
>
> Time Awake Since Boot: 6100 seconds Time Since Wake:       3100
>   seconds
>
> System Integrity Protection: enabled
>
> Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
>
> Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV) Exception Codes:
>   KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x000000000000003c Exception Note:
>   EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

I installed the new Mac Sierra & installed the latest scala-ide (scala-SDK-4.4.1-vfinal-2.11-macosx.cocoa.x86_64.zip) but its showing above error on opening the application.

Comment: Have the same problem here, downloaded it, unzipped it, there was a security warning, allowed the app to run, crashed. Any solution?

Answer (score 1):

I also faced the same issue in sierra. 
There seems to be some issue with unzipping in sierra.
Both double click as well as unzip command.
I ended up using windows (i had windows VM in VMFusion) and used 7zip to uncompress the zip. After that, it open properly in Mac.

Answer (score 1):

I have a **workaround** if you find interesting:

```
brew install Caskroom/cask/scala-ide
```

It worked for me and installed the version 4.4.1 on macOS Sierra 10.12.1.

***Note***: You will need to have brew installed so for instructions on that check this url: http://brew.sh .

Answer (score 0):

I didn't dig deep into this, but it looks like it may be an error of the Mac OS X utility that automatically compresses files.
I have downloaded the zip, uncompressed it via unzip, and it worked (launched via command line).

Comment: Are you also using Sierra?

Comment: But Mac Sierra version is 10.12, please check with new OS MAC SIERRA

Comment: Sorry, v. 10.12.1 (typo)

Answer (score 0):

I was having same issue with Eclipse Kepler when double clicking to unzip a .tar.gz file. The above reference about using Terminal worked for me.

Instead of double clicking to unsip a .zip or a .tar.gz file, try using Terminal to cd to the same directory as the downloaded file, and run command

For a .zip file:
unzip -a foo.zip

For a .tar.gz file:
gunzip -c foo.tar.gz | tar xopf -

while replacing 'foo' with name of your downloaded file.

I was also required to download and install legacy Java 6 runtime.

Reference:
http://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/magma/faq/extract

Answer (score 0):

Scala IDE is not compatible with Java SE 9 and higher versions. You might need to downgrade or install Java SE 8 in order to fix the issue.

**Lets go through each step how you can fix it.**

**Step 1.** Check what version of Java you have installed on your machine.

Run this command in your terminal: `/usr/libexec/java_home --verbose`

[image]

As you can see I have three different versions of java running on my machine.

**Step 2**: Install Java SE 8 (jdk1.8) if you don't find it in your list. Refer this [blog](http://www.dataneb.com/single-post/2018/05/14/Installing-Java-on-Oracle-Linux-7) for java installation steps.

**Step 3:** Now open your .bashrc file (run command: `vi ~/.bashrc`) and copy-paste below line in your bashrc file.

```
export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8)
```

**Step 4:** Save the file (:wq!) and reload your profile (`source ~/.bashrc`)

**Step 5:** Now you need to define eclipse.ini arguments in order to use Java 1.8 version.
On a Mac OS X system, you can find eclipse.ini by right-clicking (or Ctrl+click) on the Scala IDE executable in Finder, choose Show Package Contents, and then locate eclipse.ini in the Eclipse folder under Contents.

[image]

The path is often /Applications/Scala IDE.app/Contents/Eclipse/eclipse.ini

**Step 6:** Open it with text editor and copy-paste below line in `eclipse.ini` file. Change the version (if needed) according to your java version. Mine is 1.8.0_171.

```
-vm
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_171.jdk/Contents/Home/bin
```

**Step 7:** Save the file and exit.

**Step 8:** Run the Scala IDE application now and it should run:

[image]

Reference: [Website](https://www.dataneb.com/post/scala-ide-metadata-log-error-fix-mac)

Answer (score -1):

Facing the same error using macOS 10.12.5. Tried using different unzipped and home-brew.
Finally made it:
Installed it using `brew cask install scala-ide`. Changed the default workspace to "workspace_new" when getting asked at the first start.